# MySQL query, returns result despite not matching HAVING statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query (rarely run so can be inefficient)

```
SELECT
  FileId as Id,
  1 as IsFile,
  0 as IsDir,
  Backend as MajorType,
  SpecificId as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  Folder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Files

UNION

SELECT
  FolderId as Id,
  0 as IsFile,
  1 as IsDir,
  `Type` as MajorType,
  0 as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  ParentFolder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Folders

HAVING InFolder=2;
```

and I get a row back with "InFolder" actually being 1. Despite the having.

So I'm guessing that is because the having part is applying just to the second part of the union, how do I rephrase the query? (It will be a view when it is finished, but until then...)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    FileId as Id,
    1 as IsFile,
    0 as IsDir,
    Backend as MajorType,
    SpecificId as MinorType,
    Flags,
    Name,
    Folder as InFolder,
    Created,
    Modified
  FROM FileSystem_Files

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    FolderId as Id,
    0 as IsFile,
    1 as IsDir,
    `Type` as MajorType,
    0 as MinorType,
    Flags,
    Name,
    ParentFolder as InFolder,
    Created,
    Modified
  FROM FileSystem_Folders
) AS t
WHERE t.InFolder=2;
```

Note that `HAVING` is not the same as `WHERE`. `WHERE` is for conditions on rows, whereas `HAVING` is for conditions on groups.

Comment: Not quite true with `HAVING` - WHERE applies to selecting rows from tables, HAVING is selecting rows from a result set (the optimiser might move them about but having is after the WHERE stage)

Comment: Otherwise good idea. This is a WHERE statement because I am choosing rows from t WHERE a condition is matched.

Comment: (That is how HAVING operates on group data, the stuff you are filtering for can't be done at the row selecting phase)

Comment: "Do not use `HAVING` for items that should be in the `WHERE` clause." cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

You need not use HAVING since you don't have a GROUP BY clause in your queries.
A simple nested query with a WHERE clause will suit your needs -

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT
  FileId as Id,
  1 as IsFile,
  0 as IsDir,
  Backend as MajorType,
  SpecificId as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  Folder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Files

UNION

SELECT
  FolderId as Id,
  0 as IsFile,
  1 as IsDir,
  `Type` as MajorType,
  0 as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  ParentFolder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Folders) COMBINED_VIEW
WHERE COMBINED_VIEW.InFolder=2;
```

Comment: You can even avoid the UNION altogether, i don't see why you need it here!

Comment: The OP needs the UNION because they're selecting from two different tables, `Filesystem_Files` and `Filesystem_Folders`.

Answer (score -1):

could this work?

```
SELECT
  FileId as Id,
  1 as IsFile,
  0 as IsDir,
  Backend as MajorType,
  SpecificId as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  Folder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Files
WHERE InFolder=2

UNION

SELECT
  FolderId as Id,
  0 as IsFile,
  1 as IsDir,
  `Type` as MajorType,
  0 as MinorType,
  Flags,
  Name,
  ParentFolder as InFolder,
  Created,
  Modified
FROM FileSystem_Folders
WHERE InFolder=2
```

Comment: No, that was my first attempt (error was "unknown field" which makes sense as there isn't a InFolder in FileSystem_Folders)

Comment: forgive my negligence, but then isn't your query going to select records from `FileSystem_Files` table only?

Comment: No, it combines results from two tables.